# What is this style of mixing 3D elements with 2D elements and perspective called?

Tags: 3d, terminology, perspective

[image]

I'm curious if there’s a specific term for this style.

Comment: I would highly doubt there's a specific term for this. Something similar is a [heads-up display](https://www.google.com/search?q=heads-up+display&num=20&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwxuGf16fgAhUQZd8KHSWWDEgQ_AUIDygC&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25)

Comment: @Zach I think the car picture here clouded your judgement. This isn't anywhere close to what a heads-up display is. It's a picture of 3D and 2D portions. The windscreen of my car is neither a picture, nor does it contain drawings of 3D objects alongside the 2D ones.